# Series fill forward for string/text values

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer

I've noted that ADX has a "series fill forward" function for numeric values as per this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-fill-forwardfunction.

Is there one for a series of string/text values? I have a column of text which is sparsely filled, and I'd like to fill forward.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the input data, and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no explicit function in KQL to fill an array of strings, but it is possible to achieve it using [mv-apply](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator):

```
let data = datatable(arr: dynamic)
[
    dynamic([null,null,"abc","gwf",null,null,"asd","cfe","ars",null,null])   
];
data 
| mv-apply with_itemindex=idx arr_filled = arr on 
(
    extend fillIndex = iff(isnull(arr_filled), 0, idx)
    | extend fillIndex = row_cumsum(fillIndex, fillIndex != 0)
    | extend arr_filled = arr[fillIndex]  
    | summarize arr_filled = make_list_with_nulls(arr_filled)
)
| project arr = arr_filled
```